# iframes broken in mobile browser from focus issues

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, iframe, focus, mobile-safari

Help with outrageous focus events in iframe on mobile safari/chrome.

Currently working on a crm web application where we decided to use iframes in order to isolate the client-side logic so as to not cause a loss of work/data-entry on any other forms that may be open - I understand that in and of itself is enough to entertain a plethora of opinions and debate - this is NOT what I'm asking about...

The structure of the page is as follows:

Fixed position header
Fixed position left-nav/menu
Fixed position main content

i.e.

```
<body>
<nav id="header" style="position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; height: 50px;">
(...your imagination here...)
</nav> 
<aside id="leftNav" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 50px; bottom: 0; width: 225px">
(...even 
</aside>
<section id="mainContent" style="position: fixed; left: 225px; top: 50px; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch">
<div id="loadingImage"></div>
<iframe id="frame_1" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%" src="..."></iframe>
</section>
</body>
```

I have the touchmove event disabled, but the #mainContent still has the ability to scroll. The issue I'm running into is (in mobile-safari) when a user touches an input rendered below the top fold (from what I can tell), the keyboard is displayed and the main section scrolls the the input into view - only, it doesn't... see this is when I start thinking about drinking... the scrollable element seems to 'bounce' the screen causing it to repaint - which then scrolls the main section to the top, hiding the selected input - or in some rare cases, actually triggering a click event at the coordinates less the scrollTop value (scrolled down 300px, clicked an input but now the input 300px above it is selected...).

Open the same site with chrome on iPad... break out the bacardi - nothing seems to work...

I'm going mad, and for the first time in my 5yr professional career, I am desperately asking for help... Are iframes becoming the focus of negative attention from browsers? Should we reconsider our client-side structure? Any ideas would be appreciated

-Matt

Comment: So after a little stumbling I seemed to have a little more info if not an answer... it appears that scrollable tag needs a min-height to allow for the scrolling to to not bounce up. The iframe was created with a 'display: none;' so I'm guessing mobile-safari needs the scrollHeight for the parent element (which is scrolling) but that is determined by the iframe... setting display to block, and 'visibility: hidden' along with an onload event setting the iframe's min-height (calculating the scrolling tag's scrollHeight) seems to be working - at least on mobile-safari, 
chrome is still jacked...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it turns out that the css property for '-webkit-appearance: none' for elements rendered in the iframe is causing the problem - removing the css seems to allow the iframe's scrolling height to adjust correctly now, ultimately not bouncing when focus events are triggered... I will say that it's not bullet proof - every once in while it will go all "crazy", but who are we kidding... I have an iPad so my kids can play angry birds, not to actually to anything remotely related to "work";

: ~ )

-matt